# How do I wrap multiline Ruby arguments in HAML?

Tags: ruby, haml, word-wrap

How can I use multiple lines for a single Ruby statement in HAML? For example, I'd like to write something like the following:

```
- entries = [{
-   :title => "The Fellowship of the Ring", 
-   :body => "We should walk instead of fly"
- }]

!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Blog
  %body
    #content
      - entries.each do |entry|
        .entry
          %h3.title= entry[:title]
          %p.body= entry[:body]
```

But of course the first four lines produce a syntax error.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Wrap Arguments with Commas

According to the [HAML FAQ](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html):

> [W]hen a function has lots of arguments, it’s possible to wrap it across multiple lines as long as each line ends in a comma.

So, the following should be valid HAML:

```
- entries = [{ :title => "The Fellowship of the Ring", 
               :body  => "We should walk instead of fly" }]
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `:ruby` filter.

```
:ruby
  entries = [{ 
    :title => "The Fellowship of the Ring", 
    :body  => "We should walk instead of fly" 
  }]

!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Blog
  %body
    #content
      - entries.each do |entry|
        .entry
          %h3.title= entry[:title]
          %p.body= entry[:body]
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out the docs [here](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#multiline).

Note that it's intentionally awkward because you're not supposed to be putting lots of ruby in your templates.

Comment: I believe this is also correct so I gave an upvote but I went with CodeGnome's suggestion since it's less awkward syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
%div= "First line " + |
      "and second line" |
```

Will render:

```
<div>First line and second line</div>
```

You can use the command-tool `haml`, for instance copy the code then `pbpaste | haml` on macOS, or with a file `cat file.haml | haml`.

If you don't even want a tag:

```
First line |
and second line |
```

Will produce:

```
First line and second line
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
= link_to( |
  'Delete', |
  attachment_path(attachment),
  confirm: 'Are you sure?',
  method: :delete,
  remote: true,
  )
```

Note the pipes after both the first and second lines, and a space before the pipes!